# How do we create a temp page based upon an ID number and retrieve that ID numbers data?

Tags: php, fwrite, temporary-files

I currently have a table 'candidatedetails' containing peoples data. I can retrieve the data and show in a page if i create the page manually. However i don't want to have to manually create every page.

I have a link to each person:

`echo '<td>  <a href="'.$row['payroll_number'].'"><img src="images/document.jpg" height="30" >           </a></td>';`

This links to the unique ID (payroll_number) as 192.168.1.16/5100 (where 5100 is the payroll number in this instance)

I am trying to use the following so that when the link above is clicked on it creates a temp file and goes to a tmp page where all the candidate details are available to view

```
`<?php
$temp = tmpfile();

fwrite($temp, file_get_contents("$path/$filename"));
//Rewind to the start of file
rewind($temp);
//Read 1k from file
echo fread($temp,1024);

//This removes the file
fclose($temp);
?>`
```

[screenshot of people table with link to record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceeab.jpg)

Comment: You don't need a temp file. You need it to extract the number 5100 from the URL, go to the database and get the data for that person, and then echo the details on the screen. Unless you are dead set on having "clean" URLs like this, then it will be easier to implement yourself by having a page like "candidate.php" and then you can write `<a href="candidate.php?pr='.$row['payroll_number'].'">` ...then in candidate.php you'd use `$payrollNumber = $_GET["pr"];` to get the payroll number from the URL, so you can use it in a SQL query.

Comment: If you really want these "clean" URLs then you need a routing engine - as provided by many of the popular PHP frameworks (or you can try to find a standalone one, or even try to implement your own - but that's a big job). Even then, you'd still need the URL to be something like `/candidate/5100` so that it knows that 5100 is the ID of a candidate (as opposed to some other entity in your database) because realistically that isn't going to be the only endpoint in your application.

Comment: @ADyson
Thank you so much, this is just what i was trying to achieve. So simple but so very effective. Greatly appreciated ADyson

Comment: No problem. It's pretty much bog-standard web application functionality. A lot of tutorials and examples would demonstrate it, I think.